# Append text to a node.js stream on the go

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, node.js-stream

I am using `fs.createReadStream()` to read files, and then pipe them to the response.

I want to add a small Javascript function when I'm serving HTML files.

The only way I can think of is to read the file into a string, append the text to the string, and then stream the string to the response, but I think there could be a better/faster way to do this.

Is there a way for me to append the text to the file on the go?

Comment: You can use something like [`through`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through) to do this.  It takes a read and write function and lets you transform the stream without resorting to storing large arrays in memory.

Comment: @MatthewBakaitis Thank you for this suggestion. After reading about through and looking through its issues on github, I saw its developer recommend through2 for a case similar to mine. So, thanks mainly to you, I'm now using through2 and the issue is resolved :) Should you turn this into an anwser for me to accept it?

Comment: I think this works best as a comment.  It's not a detailed code question which is what usually is best as a detailed answer.  You might want to edit your question to add a bit at the end that says you found through2 via the comments for anybody who finds your question via search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Matthew Bakaitis's suggestion to use `through` and after reading for a while about it and checking the issues on github, I found `through`'s developer recommending [`through2`](https://github.com/rvagg/through2) 
for a case similar to mine.

**Better implementation using `finish` callback**

```
let str_to_append="Whatever you want to append"

let through_opts = { "decodeStrings": false, "encoding": "utf8" }

let chunk_handler = function (chunk, enc, next) {
    next(null, chunk)
}

let finish_handler = function (done) {
    this.push(str_to_append)
    done()
}

let through_stream = through2.ctor(through_opts, chunk_handler, finish_handler)
```

**Old Implementation**

This is how I implemented the solution:

```
var through2 = require("through2");

var jsfn="<script>function JSfn(){ return "this is a js fn";}</script>";

var flag=0;

fileStream.pipe( 
    through2( {"decodeStrings" : false, "encoding": "utf8"},function(chunk, enc) {
        if(flag===0) {
            var tempChunk=chunk;
            chunk=jsfn;
            chunk+=tempChunk;
            flag=1;
        }
        this.push(chunk);
    })
).pipe(res);
```

The option `decodeStrings` must be set to `false` so that the chunk of data is a string and not a buffer. This is related to the `transform` function of the `stream` api, not to through2.

More info on [`transform`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1)